# Android: save image from camera on canvas

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-canvas

I need to get an image from the camera and save it in over another image. How can I do this? Then I want to save this new image on the SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Here's a tutorial how to use the android's camera:
[tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

2) To overlay the cameras image over a bitmap you'll have to:
- Create a bitmap
- Create a canvas with a reference to that bitmap
- Draw the picture from the camera to the canvas.
(Since you are not making a copy of this bitmap when using the canvas, the changes will apply to the bitmap you created).

3) To save a bitmap, you can use this method I wrote:

```
/**
     * <b><i>public void writeBitmapToMemory(String filename, Bitmap bitmap)</i></b>
     * <br>
     * Since: API 1
     * <br>
     * <br>
     * Write a bitmap to the phone's internal storage.
     * 
     * @param filename 
     * The name of the file you wish to write to.
     *
     *      
     */

    public void writeBitmapToMemory(String filename, Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to the OutputStream
        try {
            fos = game.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            // this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap successfully written: " + filename);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap couldn't be written: " + filename);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Bitmap couldn't be written: " + filename);

        }

    }
```